# Overlay in wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I need a control

[image]

1. It should be asynchronous (should not block the launching thread).
2. It should block all the user interactions with background screen.
3. Backdrop shadow on background so that it gives the feeling of disabled interactions with background.

I tried  **wxBusyInfo**. It solves my first requirement, but one can interact with background window.

Then I use the **wxWindowDisabler** with wxBusyInfo, It disables the background window. But looks like events are getting buffered while disabler is on and when I am destroying wxWindowDisabler object, buffered events are firing.

Then I found **wxEventBlocker** that can be used to block the events.

Is this the right way to achieve the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

`wxBusyInfo` is the right class to do what you want, it doesn't dispatch events, so I'm not sure how do you manage to interact with anything while it is shown. Because it doesn't dispatch events -- even the repaint ones -- it's not recommended to show it for relatively long periods of time. If you need something more permanent, use `wxProgressDialog`.

Finally, `wxEventBlocker` is a rather special class which is only useful in very specific circumstances and this is not one of them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. wxBusyInfo does not dispatch events, but events are getting buffered and as moment wxBusyInfo goes off, events get processed. I am using wxDialog as parent of wxBusyInfo. wxBusyInfo has one more issue. wxBusyInfo is always on top of all the windows including other application's windows. As you said,   wxBusyInfo is not for long wait.